# How to check in Java if a string isn't drawn over another string?

Tags: java, drawstring

I am drawing some strings on a JPanel, but I dont want to these string to be drawn over each other.

How can I check if there is a string on a point on my panel?

Thanks!

Comment: What is about a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) ?

Comment: I am not using labels of other GUI objects. I am drawing strings with the DrawString() method.

Comment: LayoutManagers could be very sofisticated ...

Answer (score 0):

You need keep track on all strings and their positions, and then use `java.awt.FontMetrics` to calculate a bounding box of your strings. Then all you have to do is to check the bounding boxes for intersection.

Comment: That wont wotk for me, because I have A LOT of strings :)  and my application must be fast. I dont know if this FontMetrics is fast?

p.s. I am workting on a google maps like program.

Comment: I suppose it is faster then paint to buffer a whole JPanel and then check the color of every pixel.

Comment: You have no other choice, for my opinion, you can cache the results if you want to speed things.

either, you can fake it a little, and consider the font as a monospace with avarage char width.. therefore
myCharWidth * myCityName.length = width..
the height is easy unless you have multiline texts or text wrapping.